# Extension API - Task Provider - Build Task example

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks

I've built an extension for a programming language that I use and I've created hotkey shortcuts for calling the compiler executable with the currently open document's URI. I want to convert that to a build task in my extension. I have made a `tasks.json` file with a build task that works and catches errors and such, but it only works if I put it in the current workspace.

There are absolutely no examples of adding a build task anywhere and the [API documentation for task providers](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/task-provider) is specifically for Ruby Rakefiles or something. I'm just wanting to make a shell executable build task with a problem matcher. Can anyone give me an example of that?

Answer (score 17):

Here's a minimal [`TaskProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TaskProvider) implementation that simply runs `echo "Hello World"` in the shell:

[image]

[image]

```ts
'use strict';
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    var type = "exampleProvider";
    vscode.tasks.registerTaskProvider(type, {
        provideTasks(token?: vscode.CancellationToken) {
            var execution = new vscode.ShellExecution("echo \"Hello World\"");
            var problemMatchers = ["$myProblemMatcher"];
            return [
                new vscode.Task({type: type}, vscode.TaskScope.Workspace,
                    "Build", "myExtension", execution, problemMatchers)
            ];
        },
        resolveTask(task: vscode.Task, token?: vscode.CancellationToken) {
            return task;
        }
    });
}
```

The task definition (first argument for `new Task()`) needs to be contributed via `package.json` and [can have additional properties if needed](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/task-provider#task-definition):

```json
"contributes": {
    "taskDefinitions": [
        {
            "type": "exampleProvider"
        }
    ]
}
```

Extensions with a task provider should activate when the *Tasks: Run Task* command is executed:

```json
"activationEvents": [
    "onCommand:workbench.action.tasks.runTask"
]
```

And finally, the problem matcher(s) you want to reference need to be contributed in the `package.json`'s `contributes.problemMatchers` section.