# VSCode TaskProvider - no tasks in the menu

Tags: visual-studio-code, task, is-empty

I am trying to implement VSCode extension which provides some task. I followed what is described here
[Extension API - Task Provider - Build Task example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55135876/extension-api-task-provider-build-task-example) (except problem matchers, I don't need them) in vscode extension generated by yo. The extension gets activated when I click on Terminal -> Run Task. I see in the list exampleProvider folder, but if I click on it, it is empty. From what I know, everything is on its place. I must be missing some piece of the puzzle. Google revealed only similar unanswered problem. Could you, please help? You can see my sample code here: https://github.com/prqek/taskprovider_test

Thank you

P.

Comment: what is the use of having `vsc-extension-quickstart.md` in the repo

Comment: @rioV8 That's an automatically generated file when a directory is initialized for extension development.

Comment: @A.Donda I know, it has absolutely no function in the extension, it is some help file for the developer, it should be in `.gitignore` and .vscodeignore` or just deleted

Answer (score 0):

You can take example on how VSCode 1.74 (Nov. 2022) implements adding a task section to terminal dropdown: see [PR 165553](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/165553/files)

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/29464607/200067057-f6168bf1-5f0e-4876-9118-a6e266c09f7d.png]
(This can be tested today with [VSCode Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/))

That can be an code to follow in order to add your own entry to your menu.